# SQL double primary key, many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to connect 3 tables. In one of them I must use a compound primary key. I know, how to deal with single. I have the following tables to connect:

```
CREATE TABLE Med_list
(
    ID_med_list INT IDENTITY(200001,1)  ,
    No_med_list INT,
    ID_med INT REFERENCES Med(ID_med), 

    PRIMARY KEY(ID_med_list, No_med_list) 
)

CREATE TABLE Med
(
    ID_med INT IDENTITY(3001,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    Name VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Visit 
(
    ID_Visit INT IDENTITY(600001,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_patient INT REFERENCES Patients(ID_patient),
    Visit_date Datetime,
    ID_med_duty INT,
    No_med_list INT
)
```

I would like to every patient could have more than one medicine during one visit. I don't know how to connect table `Visit` and `Med_list` the way acceptable to SQL Server.
Thank you in advance for every hint or help:)

Comment: What is the purpose of `Med_list.No_med_list`? That table is unique on just `ID_med_list` so I think your primary key is too loose.

Answer (score 1):

You need a many to many relation, if Med_list is supposed to be this relation (medicine to visits) then you are only missing one foreign key that points to the visit so the tables relation looks like this

Patient.  <---  Visit. <---  Med_list.  --->  Meds

The tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Med_list
(
    ID_med_list INT IDENTITY(200001,1)  ,
    No_med_list INT,
    ID_med INT REFERENCES Med(ID_med),
    ID_Visit INT REFERENCES Visit(ID_Visit)
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_med_list, No_med_list) 
)

CREATE TABLE Med
(
    ID_med INT IDENTITY(3001,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    Name VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Visit 
(
    ID_Visit INT IDENTITY(600001,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID_patient INT REFERENCES Patients(ID_patient),
    Visit_date Datetime,
    ID_med_duty INT,
    No_med_list INT
)
```

And your query can look like this

```
Select * From patients p
Join Visit v on v.ID_Patient = p.ID_Patient
Join Med_list ml on ml.ID_Visit = v.ID_Visit
Join Med m on m.ID_med = ml.ID_med
```

Comment: Should't I change anything in my code? It's only part of all. And it will not be as one, whole part.

Comment: Yes, i edited my response, there might be some columns you don't need, but since i don't know the whole database structure i left them there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

I am also new in many-to-many relationship query.

**[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ddc3/1)**

```
SELECT 
  P.name,
  M.Name
FROM 
  med_list ML 
LEFT JOIN med M ON m.ID_med=ML.ID_med
LEFT JOIN visit V ON V.ID_Visit=ML.ID_Visit 
LEFT JOIN patients P ON P.ID_patient=V.ID_patient
```